# My Source Tree showing empty suddenly

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I am using source tree for the past 8 months. Today after committing some changes my Source tree suddenly changes to empty screen and there is no branches or changes.

[image]

Comment: You've tried closing/reopening the program? And rebooting the machine?

Comment: I have rebooted the program and machine multiple times. but same issue occuring.

Comment: Tried opening a repo?

Comment: if i open a new repo!, then i will lose my uncomitted changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working when i go to lower version of Source Tree.